# What is the format of Google's acquireToken?

Tags: javascript, authentication, encryption, google-api, base64

I'd like to find out if anyone's encountered a "token" that is used by a somewhat obscure Google service, which I am being vague about due to potential NDA aspects.

It is embedded as a form input and named  "acquireToken". It's base64 encoded, and appears like so:

```
<a href="https : // a-google-service . com ? acquireToken=AOV9r7psYLcqC3OhrsY">Link</a>
```

Decoding always results in the initial bytes of:

```
0x00 0xE5 0x7D 0xAF 0xBA
```

There is variable length of the token, which is consistent: These tokens control access to specific resources. Accessing resource "A" always has a token **length** of 123, for example. However, 123 might also access resource "C".  "A" and "C" will always have a length of 123, but 123 could also access other things.  There are about 10 different lengths (payloads), typically 700-800 bytes.

None of the data following the header or signature is ever the same, even for a known same resource.

Since Google is a black-hole, from whence it's impossible to even find someone to try to  obtain answers from, I'm wondering if anyone else has come across this in the wild.

If this were just a typical token, the length would be the same.  I can't find any reference to that signature (or even the initial Base64 portion, of AOV9r7!).  Additionally, I don't believe the tokens are unique to me, in that other people have similar format.  I notice Microsoft has a similarly named token, but nothing looks comparable.

I know this is a huge longshot, given there isn't a single result on any of this on Google.

Example (truncated):

```
00000000  00 E5 7D AF BA 86 0C D2 20 20 1D B3 44 0D 57 F6  |.å}¯º..Ò  .³D.Wö|
00000010  96 91 5B 29 BC E9 CC 78 FA 05 95 B9 51 9B A7 3A  |..[)¼éÌxú..¹Q.§:|
```

Comment: I am curious as to what you mean by acquireToken

Comment: That is the passed form parameter from the client to the server.

Comment: Google uses, access tokens, refresh tokens, id tokens, authorization code.    I have never heard the term acquire token used with googles authorization server.

Comment: It's their term and it's for a Google property. Otherwise, it's not so much relevant to my question as to whether anyone recognizes the signature or content format.

Comment: If its their term please link it in the documentation.  I have not been able to find this term anywhere in the docs. [oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

Comment: What documentation? I'm sorry, it seems as though there is a communication barrier. If there were documents, I wouldn't need to ask a question here. I'll try to clarify my question a bit!

Comment: I just linked you the main documentation page to googles Authorization server.  [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)  which does not mention an acquireToken so where are you getting this from exactly   All google apis require an access token  If you can tell me where your getting that from I can help you figure out what it is.

Comment: I have done quite a bit of googleing the only thing i can find is Microsoft bi has a method called acquireToken() which returns an access token.    And a number of docs stating "how to aquire a token" again meaning an access token.   So what exactly is an acquireToken and where did you get this term.   If you do actually mean an access token.  There is no format for it really its changed a number of times over the year and if you look around you will find serval questions on that topic already no stack.

Comment: I appreciate you attempting to help, but it doesn't seem as though we're communicating well.

Obviously, I googled before posting here, and this isn't a Microsoft thing. I did edit my initial post to clarify.

This is not an Oauth2 thing; yes, Google requires that, but this is separate.

Comment: I'm not sure how to state this better or in a more clear way: Google has a very specific platform that uses links which embed these in base64, and they're named acquireToken. (This is what they show up as in the server delivered pages, and sent back as part of the GET params.)

But you can ignore all that, because it's context explaining what and where they come from, and instead, if you have some means at your disposal, or if anyone does, which I don't, explore the actual format of this and tell me if it looks like anything anyone's ever seen.

Comment: These are variable length. They always have the same 'header'/'signature'. If these were just random auth tokens, they would always be the same length. Specific ones unlock specific 'things'. 

Which leads me to believe it's some type of encryption.  Which then makes me think, someone out there may have encountered this before.  No?